# azure worker role instances in different data centers

Tags: azure

I have 2 instances of azure worker role project publish in azure cloud.

Currently i am publishing both instances to west Europe as I declared in my cloud service.

Is it possible to set one instance to west Europe and the other one to USA in one cloud service, or do I need to declare 2 cloud service - one for each region ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaling a Azure Cloud Service is available only within the region or datacenter. You will need to deploy an instance in each region.

Please check [Scaling Azure cloud services geographically across multiple data centers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046947/scaling-azure-cloud-services-geographically-across-multiple-data-centers).